# PhpStorm: Only Link to Function in included Code

Tags: php, phpstorm

In my PhpStorm project, I have the following 3 files:

sub.php:

```
<?php
    function do_something() {
        // do something
    }
?>
```

sub_debug.php:

```
<?php
    function do_something() {
        // do something with debugging
    }
?>
```

main.php:

```
<?php
    include 'sub.php';

    do_something();
?>
```

So in my main.php, I usually include `sub.php`, and only switch to `sub_debug.php` if I need to do some debugging. So at any one time, I only include one of those two PHP files, and only one `do_something()` function is in scope.

However, when I CTRL-click on the `do_something()` call in `main.php` in PhpStorm, it still informs me that there are multiple implementations and prompt me to select one.

Is it possible to configure PhpStorm to only link to `include`-d codes and not all PHP files in the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm does not take `include`/`require` statements into consideration when dealing with definitions -- it assumes (for convenience and performance reasons)  that all global entities (like functions/classes etc) are always accessible (e.g. classes can be auto loaded .. or necessary file with functions  is included/required in another place).

---

Think about this case: in your `main.php` you include another file (e.g. `include 'another.php';`) and in that `another.php` file you call `do_something();`.

Considering that `another.php` does not have any include/require statements -- how IDE should know for sure which `do_something();` to go here?

With the current approach it provides the same user experience in both cases.

---

In any case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4095 seems related to your request.

Consider watching this and related tickets (str/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.